# Maven release plugin and tagging git remote master branch

Tags: git, maven, github

I'm trying to set up a mvn release. The release works fine, but the branch tag is always in my current settings on the local master branch. All tries to tag the remote server fails.

From the logs I see following steps:

```
git add -- pom.xml
git status
git commit --verbose -F /tmp/maven-scm-1608798069.commit pom.xml
git symbolic-ref HEAD
git push pushUrl master:master
```

What I didn't like is the 'master:master'. I think that is reason why the push will be done locally. All my tries to change this to 'origin/master: origin/master' failed. On my machine I can fix this with `git push --tags` between `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform`. Because I will port this to the build server I would prefer a solution where it could be done in one flush.

Does anybody have an idea how I configure maven in the way that the tagging will be published on the remote server by using the maven plugin release or scm?

EDIT: Added scm parts of the pom.xml which I think could be relevant.

```
<scm>
    <connection>[pushUrl]</connection>
    <developerConnection>[pushUrl]</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
[...]
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</plugin>
```

The output of `git symbolic-ref HEAD` on the console is refs/heads/master.

Comment: Can you show your pom file and which version of maven-release-plugin do you use?

Comment: I attached some parts of the pom. I think it would be too long. If I understand your question correct it should be possible to push the tags to the server. In the [SCM plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html) for git they are describing a way which branch is used. I do not understand the section _Working with branches_. Maybe here is the clue.

Comment: Since I got it to run on Jenkins, I found the mistake on the console. I interpreted the sentence _Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits._ wrong, should `git pull` solved it.